# Shall I use an article with the phrase "increasing trend"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, countability

If I want to use the word increasing trend, shall I consider it countable or uncountable? i.e. should I write:

> With an increasing trend towards using the Internet, the need for security is becoming more important.

Or,

> With increasing trend towards using the Internet, the need for security is becoming more important.

Comment: There are ***no*** contexts where you could properly start an utterance with *With increasing trend*, but *With **an** increasing trend* isn't likely to be idiomatic in many contexts anyway, so if you want *me* to "endorse" the usage you'll have to ***provide a more complete context*** (the whole sentence itself, plus your explanation of exactly what you want it to *mean*).

Comment: I do not think I can post the exact sentence as the text is not published yet. However, I use it in academic context. Consider X a product. I hope that help.

Comment: @None You don't need to replace *X* and *Y* with the actual things. Simply make something up that would have the same grammatical effect. We don't actually care about what's *really* being discussed; what we do care about is *how* it's being discussed—which *X* and *Y* makes a little problematic. (I'd say *Y* is more problematic than *X* here, but both should be provided.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford I made a close example. Plz check.

Comment: In the actual example, you need an article; you would not if the noun were plural (*tends*) or if it were a particular mass noun (say, *medication*, without the words between it and the comma).

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is that 'trend' is countable and therefore needs an article when used in the singular.

A rough rule of thumb is that if you can add an s to a noun to create a plural in the context in which you want to use it, it's countable. Plus, a dictionary will usually give examples using articles with countable nouns.